# Run Android preset in TestLab though gcloud CLI

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I'm having TestLab preset for our testing device matrix and I would like to target run this preset through the gcloud CLI (https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/command-line)
Am I blind or is there no way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Martin's answer is correct, but leaves out an alternative way to create and store your preset group(s) in a yaml-formatted argument file. E.g. create a `presets.yaml` file with:

```
device-preset-1:
  device:
    - {model: Nexus6, version: 21, locale: en, orientation: portrait}
    - {model: Nexus6, version: 21, locale: de, orientation: landscape}
    - {model: Nexus7, version: 19, locale: fr}

device-preset-2:
  device:
    - {model: Pixel2, version: 28}
    - {model: Pixel2, version: 29, orientation: landscape}
    - {model: Pixel3, version: 30, locale: es}
```

and invoke your test with:

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
  --type instrumentation \
  --app app-debug-unaligned.apk \
  --test app-debug-test-unaligned.apk
  presets.yaml:device-preset-2
```

Comment: This is a bit better to have it defined in separate file so it's bit more readable in code versioning. Thanks! Still would love to run the preset that is defined on web Firebase Console so the resulting run has better naming in the console.

Comment: Unfortunately there is currently no way for `gcloud` to pull the preset configuration from the Firebase Console.
Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "better naming in the console"? I'm not aware that there would be any difference in the test results UI.

Comment: My bad, for some reason I though it will use the preset name instead of the `matix-xxxxx` in that case, it wont make any difference

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to convert the preset to option `--device` items:

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
  --type instrumentation \

  --app app-debug-unaligned.apk \
  --test app-debug-test-unaligned.apk \

  --device model=Nexus6,version=21,locale=en,orientation=portrait \
  --device model=Nexus7,version=19,locale=fr,orientation=landscape \
  --device ...
```

Comment: That's exactly not what I want because it always creates "matrix-xxxx" run and not actually running preset define in Firebase Console